# Incorporating new changes from Upstream Git repo

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a repo and want to make some commits to the master branch of the cloned repo, and yet be able to pull in updates made to the repo I originally cloned from, whose remote I named `upstream`.

After renaming/adding remotes, `git remote -v` gives me

```
origin  https://myRepo (fetch)
origin  https://myRepo  (push)
upstream       https://repoItWasClonedFrom (fetch)
upstream       https://repoItWasClonedFrom  (push)
```

Will it be possible with this setup? After making a few commits to my `master` branch, how should I pull new changes from the `upstream` branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git pull upstream master
```

or

```
git pull --rebase upstream master
```

if you prefer git to rebase your commits instead of merging them.

See https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html.

Comment: How do I decide between rebase and merge?

Comment: It depends entirely on how you want the history to look like, if you want to submit a pull request to the original repo, etc.